# Center fixed element horizontally minus column

Tags: css, css-position

I have a two-column layout and want a `fixed` element to be centered horizontally in the right column.

How do I accomplish this as a `fixed` element isn't position relative to it's parent but rather to the document?

Note: the left column's width is known. The right column's width is "full width".

I'm using `fixed` (and not `absolute`) because the element has to follow scrolling.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px; 
  display: flex; 
  background-color: green;}

.column {
  width: 300px; 
  background-color: pink;
}

.content {
  flex: 1; 
  background-color: green;
}

.fixed-element {
  position: fixed; 
  left: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='fixed-element'>Please center me in green area.</div>
  <div class='column'></div>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about fixed element's width, is that known?

Comment: No, the text is dynamic. It's a flash feedback message element, e.g. "Your object is saved."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc` to calculate center and `transform` for the unkown width of fixed element positioning.

Please check if the [browser compability for the calc](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is ok for you, before using it in production.

And here is my solution

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 200px; 
  display: flex; 
  background-color: green;
}
.column {
  width: 200px; 
  background-color: pink;
}

.content {
  flex: 1; 
  background-color: maroon;
}

.fixed-element {
z-index: 111;
  position: fixed;
  right: calc(50% - 205px); //can't explain that +5px :)
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='fixed-element'>Please center me</div>
  <div class='column'></div>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```